# KiCAD: Resetting pcbNew

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I have created a pcb with KiCAD.
Unfortunately, there were some errors with the pcb and i have to redraw.

The problems all lie within the pcbNew program...

My schematic, footprints and generally everything else is correct.

So i will have to redesign the pcbNew portion of the pcb.

Since i have already designed pcbNew, is there a way to revert if back to the original state (where all the parts were in the middle and i had first to sort them out)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select everything, delete it, and then update PCB from schematic.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I had an arduino shield template so there was initial order on the geometry (header pins for example). When i did that, there was no order on the shield part.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start from scratch just delete the kicad_pcb file. When you then launch pcbnew it will start will a fresh file.

You should be able to recover some of the layout by editing the kicad_pcb file, its plain text and logically structured